# How can I use a char as a counter?

Tags: replace, string, characters, numbers

I have this `LaTeX` code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[a]

\affiliation{...}

\affiliation{...}

\affiliation{...}

 ...

\affiliation{...}

\end{enumerate}
```

and, using a script written in Emacs Lisp, I want to obtain:

```
\affiliation[a]{...}

\affiliation[b]{...}

...

\affiliation[n]{...}
```

I started from the following code thinking I could change it 'quite easily' in order to resolve my problem, but I failed.

Here it is my code:

```
(perform-replace "\\\\affiliation{"
     `((lambda (data count)
                   (concat "\\\\affiliation{"(number-to-string (+ 1 count))"}"))) nil t nil 1 nil a z)
```

How can I modify `number-to-string` to obtain lowercase letters instead of numbers?

A note: `\begin{enumerate}[a]` could be absent, so first occurence of `\affiliation{...}` is replaced using the following code:

```
(perform-replace "\\\\begin{enumerate}\\[a\\]\n\n\\\\affiliation{" "\n\n\\\\affiliation[a]{" t t nil 1 nil a z)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the `make-string` function.  If `count` starts at 0 and counts up, then:

```
(make-string 1 (+ ?a count))
```

will go `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.

Comment: Beware of going past `z`, however.  This function won't automatically roll over to `aa`, `ab`, etc., if that's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example, you can also use

```
C-M-% affiliation RET \&[\,(string (+ ?a \#))] RET
```

- `C-M-%` is the default binding of `query-replace-regexp`
- `affiliation` is regexp to search for
- `\&[\,(string (+ ?a \#))]` is the replacement pattern

  - `\&` is the whole match, that is, `affiliation`
  - `\,` runs a Lisp expression after it and captures the result
  - `(string char)` converts a character (number) to string
  - `\#` is the number of replacements done so far (starting with zero)

Also see `C-h f query-replace-regexp`